# simple way of adressing user defined type elements in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

im converting Oracle plsql code to Postgresql code but im stuck....

**given is following code:**

Oracle user defined Type:

```
TYPE typ_type_name is RECORD (
  typ_elem1 VARCHAR,
  typ_elem2 BOOLEAN := FALSE,
);

TYPE tab_type_name is TABLE of typ_type_name index by VARCHAR(32);
```

Oracle Procedure:

```
procedure proc_name(par_name in out nocopy typ_name)
is 
  v_name varchar(32);
BEGIN
  v_name := 'example_text';

  par_name(v_name).typ_elem1 := 'more_text';
END;
```

**what I tried in postgres so far:**

- created type <typ_type_name>
- created table with column types: <typ_type_name> so i can do some selects and index them by name (the varchar column)

**Problem:**

the way I tried it I cant use it the way like in the Oracle Procedure with:

```
par_name(v_name).typ_elem1 := 'more_text';
```

i guess the problem is the '(v_name)'

so is there an easy/simpler way of using oracles `par_name(v_name).typ_elem1 := 'more_text';` in postgresql?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot to do in PostgreSQL. PostgreSQL doesn't support text indexed arrays (collections).

Comment: but is there a workaround?

Comment: @Dolis No, there is only integer indexed arrays.

Comment: do you have any ideas on how to get the main idea of that oracle code to work in postgres? like with the help of selects on help-tables or something like that?

Comment: @Dolis - without knowledge of context I have not any idea. The collections are used on Oracle (together with bulk collect) from performance reasons. But the Postgres uses different architecture, and this pattern has not any sense there.